# How to parse html string in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i m using this code for posting and getting the data from the server.

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"any-data=%@", myData];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://your-server.com/your-script.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Data: %@",data);
```

but problem is that when i print data in nslog then it is in html formate
how i retrieve actual result in my application.

how parse data?

please give me if any refrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just scraping the HTML for data, `NSScanner` will do. If you want to display the data, a UIWebView will work. It depends on what you want to do with the HTML. You don't need an XML parser — in most cases that's overkill.

Answer (score 2):

You could always try searching 1. Around [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+parse+html), and 2. [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+parse+html).

Unfortunately attempting this is not going to be easy unless you can guarantee well formed XHTML. If your XHTML **is** indeed guaranteed to be valid then you could use [XSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You could also check out the `HTMLParser.h` code in `libxml/HTMLparser.h` which is provided by `libxml2`, in which [this link](http://veillard.com/XML/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html) may help you.

I've noticed that a lot of applications use basic String splitting for data extraction.

Comment: i search this on google as well as stackoverflow but i m not find any exact soln so i ask,

i use libxml2 but in this code it requires html file but i have php file so how i implement with HTMLparser.

Comment: If you can provide some input, some desired output, and the code you're currently using to extract this information. It may help people give you advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're feeling bold and you know what to extract from your document, have a look at [RegexKit Lite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/). Obviously, you'll have to come up with the proper regular expression that matches **exactly** what you're searching for and captures the content you're interested in.